# Compare Excel spreadsheet values with each line of text file & return output based on the result

Tags: regex, excel, vbscript, text-files

I need to compare the values in a spreadsheet with a text file containing the output of a zone transfer to get the IP addresses of specific interfaces based on the type listed in the spread sheet.

- **My input:**

  - **Excel spreadsheet:**

    ```
    +----------+------------+
    |   Name   |  Int type  |
    +----------+------------+
    | Switch-1 |            |
    | SERVER1  | Production |
    | SERVER2  | OOB        |
    | Switch-2 |            |
    | SERVER3  | Production |
    | SERVER4  | Other      |
    +----------+------------+
    ```
  - **Text file:**

    ```
    server1-prod.fqdn.com 86400 IN A 192.168.0.10
    server1-oob.fqdn.com 600 IN A 192.168.0.11
    server2-prod.fqdn.com 600 IN A 192.168.0.12
    server2-oob.fqdn.com 600 IN A 192.168.0.13
    server3-prod.fqdn.com 300 IN A 192.168.0.14
    server3-oob.fqdn.com 600 IN A 192.168.0.15
    server4-foo.fqdn.com 86400 IN A 192.168.0.16
    ```
- **My desired output:**

  ```
  Switch name: Switch-1
  Interface name: server1-prod.fqdn.com - IP Address: 192.168.0.10
  Interface name: server2-oob.fqdn.com - IP Address: 192.168.0.11
  Switch name: Switch-2
  Interface name: server3-prod.fqdn.com - IP Address: 192.168.0.12
  server4-foo.fqdn.com Unknown interface type: Other.
  ```

**My current code:**

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Server-List-by-Switch.xlsx")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("FQDN-and-IP.txt")

strNextLine = objFile.Readline
arrList = Split(objFile.ReadLIne(),vbCrLf)
intRow = 2

objFile.Close

Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
    objHostName = objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value
    objIntfType = objExcel.Cells(intRow,2).Value

    If InStr(1,objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value,"Switch-",1) > 0 Then

        Wscript.Echo vbCrLF & "Switch Name: " & objHostName

    ElseIf InStr(1,objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value,"Switch-",1) = 0 And InStr(1,objExcel.Cells(intRow,2).Value,"Production",1) > 0 then

            For Each line In arrList
                objFQDN = LCase(objHostName & "-prod.fqdn.com.")
                strFQDN = splitRE (strNextLine, "\s+")
                Wscript.Echo strFQDN(0)
                If InStr(Lcase(line),objFQDN) > 0 Then
                    strIPAddress = Right(line, Len(line) - InStrRev(line," ") )
                    Wscript.Echo "Interface name(Production): " & strFQDN & " - IP Address: " & strIPAddress
                End If
            Next

    ElseIf InStr(1,objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value,"Switch-",1) = 0 And InStr(1,objExcel.Cells(intRow,2).Value,"OOB",1) > 0 then

            For Each line In arrList
                objFQDN = LCase(objHostName & "-oob.fqdn.com.")
                strFQDN = splitRE (strNextLine, "\s+")
                Wscript.Echo strFQDN(0)
                If InStr(Lcase(line),objFQDN) > 0 Then
                    strIPAddress = Right(line, Len(line) - InStrRev(line," ") )
                    Wscript.Echo "Interface name(Production): " & strFQDN & " - IP Address: " & strIPAddress
                End If
        Next

    Else 

        Wscript.Echo objHostName & " has an unknown interface type: " & objIntfType

    End If

    intRow = intRow + 1

Loop

Function splitRE(strSource, pattern)
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern =pattern
        splitRE = Split(.Replace(strSource, " "), " ")
    End With
End Function 

objExcel.Quit
```

The only problem now is that the strFQDN variable is only populated with the 1st line of the text file, repeatedly, so the comparison fails:

server1-prod.fqdn.com.

Comment: could you please upload your data examples as images or [format like this](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)? i have absolutelly no idea what are you saying with the data :(

Comment: what comparison fails? **`strFQDN`** is never compared to anything, just echoed...

Comment: I have not tried your code but the first apparent error that I can see is `strNextLine = objFile.Readline` and `arrList = Split(objFile.ReadLIne(),vbCrLf)`.  You read the first line into strNextLine and then use it repeatedly in the main loop.  You read the second line into arrList.  You ignore the rest of the text file.  Try `arrList = Split(objFile.ReadAll(),vbCrLf)`.

Comment: Second error: `Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""`.  `objExcel` is an Excel Application. `.Cells(intRow,1).Value` needs a Worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is complicated for no obvious reason.  For example, why does the macro open workbook "C:\Server-List-by-Switch.xlsx" rather than sit within in?

I do not know what `Wscript.Echo` does so have used Debug.Print to output to the Immediate Window.  I am not a fan of having a three character type identifier at the start of each variable.  But if used, they should be correct.  So I think `objFile` is OK because it is an object but `objHostName` is wrong because it is a string.

I have simplified your code but have kept the structure.  This means this code cannot create the output line `server4-foo.fqdn.com Unknown interface type: Other.` because your code validates the Excel table rather than text file.  The code could be resequenced but you need to be clearer about the nature of the data.

I have a worksheet "Server-List-by-Switch" in a workbook.  It contains:

```
  |   A      |    B      |
1 | Name     | Intf type |
2 | Switch-1 |           |
3 | SERVER1  | Production| 
4 | SERVER2  | OOB       |
5 | Switch-2 |           |
6 | SERVER3  | Production| 
7 | SERVER4  | Other     |
```

The macro's output is:

```
Switch Name: Switch-1
Interface name: server1-prod.fqdn.com - IP Address: 192.168.0.10
Interface name: server2-oob.fqdn.com - IP Address: 192.168.0.13
Switch Name: Switch-2
Interface name: server3-prod.fqdn.com - IP Address: 192.168.0.14
SERVER4 has an unknown interface type: Other
```

which is as close as I can get without resequencing the code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GenIPAddressReport()

  Dim arrList() As String
  Dim FQDN As String
  Dim FQDNPart() As String
  Dim HostName As String
  Dim IntfType As String
  Dim intRow As Long
  Dim IPAddress As String
  Dim Line As Variant
  Dim LinePart() As String
  Dim objFile As Object
  Dim objFSO As Object

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\FQDN-and-IP.txt")

  arrList = Split(objFile.ReadAll(), vbCrLf)

  objFile.Close
  Set objFile = Nothing

  'For Each Line In arrList
  '  Debug.Print Line
  'Next

  intRow = 2
  With Worksheets("Server-List-by-Switch")

  Do Until .Cells(intRow, 1).Value = ""
    HostName = .Cells(intRow, 1).Value
    IntfType = .Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    If InStr(1, HostName, "Switch-") > 0 Then
      Debug.Print "Switch Name: " & HostName
    ElseIf InStr(1, HostName, "Switch-") = 0 And _
           InStr(1, IntfType, "Production") > 0 Then
      For Each Line In arrList
        FQDN = LCase(HostName & "-prod.fqdn.com")
        LinePart = Split(LCase(Line), " ")
        If FQDN = LinePart(0) Then
          Debug.Print "Interface name: " & LinePart(0) & _
                      " - IP Address: " & LinePart(UBound(LinePart))
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    ElseIf InStr(1, HostName, "Switch-") = 0 And _
           InStr(1, IntfType, "OOB") > 0 Then
      For Each Line In arrList
        FQDN = LCase(HostName & "-oob.fqdn.com")
        LinePart = Split(LCase(Line), " ")
        If FQDN = LinePart(0) Then
          Debug.Print "Interface name: " & LinePart(0) & _
                      " - IP Address: " & LinePart(UBound(LinePart))
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Else
       Debug.Print HostName & " has an unknown interface type: " & IntfType
    End If
    intRow = intRow + 1
  Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: its marked as **vbscript**, not *vba*, why are you talking about macros? and a few comments in the code would help.. anyway, +1 for getting closer to what OP asked for ;)

Comment: @deathApril.  I came to the question via its `excel` tag and had not noticed the `vbscript` tag.  I should have guessed from the `Echo` command it wasn't vba.  I wondered about more comments but I have not added anything much; I saw my actions as more of a tidy and a correct.

Answer (score 0):

just a wild guess - replace both

*`strFQDN = splitRE (strNextLine, "\s+")`* with

`strFQDN = splitRE (line, "\s+")`

---

or update `strNextLine` with other lines, now it is always the first line..

Comment: Hi deathApril, that would only compare the results of the array read in from the text file to the results of the array read from the text file.  I need to compare the hostnames in the spreadsheet to the first array item of each record lifted from the text file.

Comment: i'm lost in your explanation i'm affraid, but you only update `strNextLine = objFile.Readline` just this time, never again, so it is always the first line...

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the issue.  How do I get it to iterate all the lines of the text file until it finds a match?

Comment: if you edit your question to answer my comments to the question, i might be able to help more, now i have no idea what are you talking about :(

Comment: I want to update strNextLine with a new line from the text file repeatedly until it finds a match to the Excel spreadsheet value popluated in objFQDN or it reached the end of the file.  Is this enough info?

Comment: no, but another wild guess - add `strNextLine = objFile.Readline` between the `Until` and `For` cycles...

Comment: OK, that allowed me to populate the strNextLine variable with the first few lines of the text file (for as many lines as were in the spreadsheet.  What I need to do is compare each value in the spread sheet to every FQDN in the text file until I find a match then out put the matching FQDN & IP address.  I'm not sure how to make this clearer.  Based on the Excel file input & text file input listed above I need to compare each server name with all the FQDNs then output the correct FQDN & IP address based on the 2nd value in the spreadsheet.

Comment: as i've said in a comment to the question, i have no idea how your input files look like

Comment: They're listed at the top of this page in my first post under Excel spreadsheet and Text file.  Above where it says desired output.

Comment: in excel, everything is in 1 column?

Comment: It hasn't preserved the whitespace I originally added, but anything with a space between it is in a different column.  There are 2 columns.  Hostname & Interface Type. I can read from the Excel spreadsheet.  That's not the issue I'm having.  I need to read in the contents of the text file to an array after breaking it up using the splitRE function so that I can get the FQDNs only to compare with the objFQDN variable.